# Displaying validation control in a div tag

Tags: css

I have a div tag for which i have defined a border.
i have given the validation control inside the div tag
Now before clicking the "submit" i get to see the div tag and border. -> how to avoid this
Now after clicking the "submit" i get to see the div tag and border-> which is exptected and correct.

My question how to hide the border in the div tag before clicking the "submit" button or on the click 
of the "cancel" button

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate a bit more? Also showing some code never hurts

Answer (score 0):

You can't with css. You need javascript to do this.

```
<input type=submit onclick="removeborder(this)" />

function removeborder(obj) {
  obj.style.borderStyle = "none";
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Valdiation summary is displayed on click of 'submit' and get removed on 'cancel' button. Since i have the validation summary inside the div tag with a border - this border is displayed.

Comment: Be more clear, code examples, etc if you want a more clear answer. You give to little info.

Comment: <div class="errorcolumns">
                Validation Errors*
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valDataGroup" ShowSummary="true" DisplayMode="BulletList"  ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Small"/>
            </div>

Comment: .errorcolumns
{
    width:558px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border: 1px solid #680B6E;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    
}